# Requisitar o ID do super usuário no Django e fazer um "if" com ele

Tags: django

Estou tentando pegar o ID do super usuário no django e fazer uma decisão a partir disso, mas ao colocar o valor capturado no comando "if" a aplicação ignora o 'if' e passa direto para o "else".
A questão é: Eu ja olhei e confirmei que o super usuario está usando o ID 1 mas o programa está ignorando o 'if' e indo direto para o 'else'.

**Na pasta de 'urls.py' está assim:**

```
path('agenda/', views.lista_eventos),
```

**Na pasta de views.py está assim:**

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def lista_eventos(request):
    usuario_model = request.user
    
    if usuario_model == 1:      #se for o super usuário mostre todos os registros
        evento = Evento.objects.all()
        dados = {'eventos': evento}
        return render(request, 'agenda.html', dados)
    else:              #se não for o super usuário mostre apenas os registros deste usuário
        evento = Evento.objects.filter(usuario = usuario_model)
        dados = {'eventos': evento}
        return render(request, 'agenda.html', dados)

# "Evento" é o model contendo as informações e a foreignKey declarada assim: usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que esta ação:

```
usuario_model = request.user
```

Não retorna o ID do usuário logado, ela retorna o atributo `username` do usuário logado.

Conforme pode ver no código fonte da classe [AbstractBaseUser](https://github.com/django/django/blob/5d13cc540e29eedafe695338d8ec9ec500185ccd/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L65) no projeto Django, A classe `django.contrib.auth.models.User` herda de `AbstractUser` que herda de
`AbstractBaseUser` é nesta classe que é possível ver a implementação concreta do método `__str__(self)`, que vai retornar o valor do atributo `username`.

Então será necessário mudar a lógica o seu código.

Minha sugestão seria:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def lista_eventos(request):
    usuario = request.user
    usuario_model = User.objects.get(username=usuario)
    if usuario_model.id == 1:
        evento = Evento.objects.all()
        dados = {'eventos': evento}
        return render(request, 'agenda.html', dados)
    else:
        evento = Evento.objects.filter(usuario = usuario_model)
        dados = {'eventos': evento}
        return render(request, 'agenda.html', dados)
```

Para garantir ainda mais o código eu colocaria uma verificação para saber se é superuser. A versão final do código ficaria:

```
 @login_required(login_url='/login/')
    def lista_eventos(request):
        usuario = request.user
        usuario_model = User.objects.get(username=usuario)
        if usuario_model.id == 1 and usuario_model.is_superuser:
            evento = Evento.objects.all()
            dados = {'eventos': evento}
            return render(request, 'agenda.html', dados)
        else:
            evento = Evento.objects.filter(usuario = usuario_model)
            dados = {'eventos': evento}
            return render(request, 'agenda.html', dados)
```